# How to get Explain Plan in Oracle using SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy ORM, I would like to get the explain plan for an Oracle query.

This would be done in sqlplus using 2 steps that look something like this:

```
# step 1  
explain plan for select * from table_xyz;

# step 2
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(null, null, 'SERIAL'));
```

I have tried the following so far with SQLAlchemy ORM without luck:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import os

# create engine
user, pswd = (os.environ['USER'], os.environ['PW'])
conn_str = f'oracle://{user}:{pswd}@myDbService'
engine =  create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)

# create session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# reflect existing table
MyTable = Table('my_table', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, schema='myschema')

# generate query
bind_param = dict('state_cd'=['CA', 'WA'])
query = str(Session().query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.c.my_state_cd.in_(state_cd)))
# print(query) # <-- this returns a properly formulated select query with bound parameters
result = Session().execute('EXPLAIN PLAN FOR ' + query, bind_param)
```

Executing the last line above keeps failing with the following error and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter 'my_state_cd_2'
```

Comment: Does your query only require one parameter? There's something about the name `my_state_cd_2` which suggests multiplicity...

Comment: It requires 2 state codes: `state_cd'=['CA', 'WA']`